# How to access variable from example below

Tags: java, variables, getter

**Example**

This is the Main class..

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Man one = new Man("Bob");
    }
}
```

This is the Man class to create a new name and give him a name..

```
public class Man {
    public String name;

    public Man(String name) {
    this.name = name; 
  }
}
```

As you can see, when I made a new `Man` in the `main class` I named him `one`. How would I access the variable `one` from the `Man` class?

I tried something like:

```
public String getName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return name;
}
```

Though it doesn't work.

Comment: You can add getter to the Man class to return you the name, for example *public String getName() { return name; }*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which method of Man would need the man that you created in the main method? To do what?

Comment: You cannot learn the *very basics* of a programming language by asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you are wondering how to do this, then you certainly did not make a new "man", you copied the code from somewhere.  There exists no such thing as "man", there exists "Man".  (Case is important.)  You did not call him "one", you called him "Bob".  September, October and November passed real quick.

Comment: @MikeNakis, Yes I know, I was just trying to give an example just to know how to access that name you give the variable when you make a new man. I already know how to get the name 'Bob' that is not the issue. Also that Man and man lowercase and uppercase was the result of typing too quickly I didn't think the community would be fussy over that.

Comment: @JBNizet, I want to access the variable name from the Man class so I can just print it out. I just want to print out 'one' from the other class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The **variable name** `one` is only valid within the scope of the main method. The Man class has no clue about the names chosen for the variables pointing to its instances.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to access 'one' from the Man class at all?

Comment: What do you mean by accessing 'one' from Man class? Man class only has name inside it. and Main class have one inside it which is object of Man class.

Comment: @Raf, Can you see the line `Man one = new Man("Bob");`? I named the man `one` (not talking about his name).

Comment: Why do you want to access one in the Man class in the first place? What is your objective? What do you wish to achieve?

Comment: Okay, I don't know about you guys, but I am adding this question to my favourites.

Comment: @MikeNakis what is the purpose of favourit + ing a question ? Just curious because I noticed the favourite flag. I haven't done one yet.

Comment: @Raf, I want to access the variable name from the Man class so I can just print it out. I just want to print out 'one' from the other class.

Comment: @Raf I used to think that it will send notifications when something changes in the question or in the answers, but it turns out that no, that's not it.  The only purpose it seems to serve, sadly, is that you can later go to your profile and browse through your favourites and find it again.  Also, visitors of your profile can go to the "activity" tab and see what questions you have marked as favourites.

Comment: @MikeNakis I think they should add a subscribe functionality to notify one of any changes to the question or its answers ... thanks for the info about favourite flag, need to start using it.

Comment: @Tahmid I do not understand why you want to print  a class's property in the class itself - I can't even put it in words, sorry. This answer is the right answer to your question. In my answer I have shown how you create a class, with getters and setters and then create it's instance in other class and use its getter and setter. I advise you to do a basic reading of Java and then you will understand the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

To access properties of a class you can add getters and setters to the class. The getters return String and take no argument, setters take argument and return nothing. See below for example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        Man man = new Man("Human!"); 

        System.out.println(man.getName());
        //Human!

        man.setName("Civilised human!");

        System.out.println(man.getName());
        //Civilised human!
    }
}

class Man {
    String name; 

    public Man(String name) {
        this.name = name; 
    }

    //getter for Man class 
    public String getName() {
        return name; 
    }

    //setter for Man class
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name; 
    }
}
```

You can also access the properties of the class without getter if they are publicly accessible like below in your case:

```
System.out.print(man.name);
```

Comment: I am afraid you did not understand the question.  He wants to "access the variable one from the Man class".  The **Man** class.  (Talking about unfortunate naming choices...)

Comment: @MikeNakis I am confused, but you could be right, naming can lead to disaster

Comment: Well, he probably won't give you that point, so here it is for the effort!  C-:=

Comment: Well thank you for your support and encouragement, I hope he give the points to **tschaena** for getting it right.